# How to format time to "H:i:s" in laravel using carbon

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I would like to find total time spent on a project given that the user enters the "start time" and "stop time". I have been able to access the time spent but it comes as an array of Date Interval.

I want to just format the results to "H:i:s" (Hour:Minute:Seconds)

Here's the code from my controller

I have already declare the use of Carbon Class(use Carbon/Carbon;) at the top of the controller

```
    $start = Carbon::parse($request->strt_time);
    $end = Carbon::parse($request->stp_time);
    $time_spent = $end->diff($start);

    $spent_time = $time_spent->format('H:i:s');
```

I expect the output to be 00:00:00 but I am getting a string "H:i:s"

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($time_spent);`?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you tried dumping all variables along the way to check their **real** content?

Comment: I get a string 'H:i:s' - @aynber

Comment: Your format string should be `'%H:%i:%s'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

diff() method gives CarbonInterval, which inherits the format function from DateInterval. The documentation states that Each format character must be prefixed by a percent sign (%)

```php
 DateInterval::format ( string $format ) : string


 $january = new DateTime('2010-01-01');
 $february = new DateTime('2010-02-01');
 $interval = $february->diff($january);

 // %a will output the total number of days.
 echo $interval->format('%a total days')."\n";

 // While %d will only output the number of days not already covered by the
 // month.
 echo $interval->format('%m month, %d days');
```

so final solution is

```php
$end->diff($start)->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it. I see no difference to the original code

Comment: This answer is correct, but lacks the explanation. `$time_spent` is a CarbonInterval, which inherits the format function from DateInterval. [The documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) states that `Each format character must be prefixed by a percent sign (%).`

Comment: Many thanks everyone... It worked now... I really appreciate...

Comment: @Micsedinam if it works please accept this answer.

Comment: @AkashKumarVerma Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

From the [Carbon documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference):

> ### [Difference](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference)
>
> As Carbon extends `DateTime` it inherit its methods such as `diff()`
> that take a second date object as argument and returns a
> `DateInterval` instance.
>
> We also provide `diffAsCarbonInterval()` act like `diff()` but returns
> a `CarbonInterval` instance. Check [`CarbonInterval`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval) chapter for more
> information.

So, as [Akash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063536/7117697) suggested, you could do:

```php
$spent_time = $end->diff($start)->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

Why the `%` is prefixed in every variable? As @aynber pointed out, [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) states:

> Each format character must be prefixed by a percent sign (%).

Another option is to make use of the `gmdate()` helper:

```php
$duration = $end->diffInSeconds($start);
$spent_time = gmdate('H:i:s', $duration);
```

or just:

```php
$spent_time = gmdate('H:i:s', $end->diffInSeconds($start));
```

Comment: It's just `H:i:s` in `\Carbon\Carbon`. ie. `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($event['start'])->timezone('Australia/Perth')->format('H:i:s');`